# How to batch process a Flowable output in a chain in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

How do I chain processes to be processed in batches in RxJava2. the flow diagram below is what I like to achieve.

```
Flowable#1          Flowable#2 (process every 10)
==============     ================================
callServer(p1) ->
      :        ->  saveToDatabase(List<r1 to r10>)
callServer(p20)->  saveToDatabase(List<r11 to r20>)
callServer(p21)->      :
      :                :
callServer(p35)->  saveToDatabase(List<r31 to r35>) //the remainder
```

currently, what I have is to wait for all the results to be returned before saving into database.

```
Flowable.fromIterable(paramList)
    .map(p -> callServer(p)) 
    //wait for the return a map of ALL the results r  
    //how to chain it such that saveToDatabase process after 'n' results 
    .toList()  
    .flatmap(listOfR -> saveToDatabase(listOfR);
```

How do I make it such that the saveToDatabase is called after every 'n' results instead of waiting for all the results to be completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [buffer()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(int)) operator with n as parameter, buffer will collect n items from the source `Observable` and will emit List with n items.
So you can process each n items at once, and save them to database

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, if you need to process every `n` seconds, then one of the windowing operators are appropriate.